# Laravel livewire model is not working when updating input field from javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a text input field which works great if I update it myself when typing inside it, however, what I need is to have this input field be populated with data from javascript, rather than the user.
This is my input field

```
<input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="images" wire:model="images">
```

This is what happens if I type "123" in the input field, I get this for the input field's value:

[image]

However when I update it using javascript, `document.getElementById("images").value = "Hello"`
The input field is populated with the new data:
[image]

But it doesn't make a new fetch call to get the data and the last one is with the "123" data that was inserted without javascript...

[image]

Any idea of how it can get the data after updating the input's value from javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After changing the value of the input using javascript, you can trigger the input event to make livewire update the model.

```
document.getElementById("images").value = 'Hello';
document.getElementById("images").dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

If you're using wire:model.lazy, you should use a 'change' event instead of 'input'

Comment: Thanks bro, i am very new to livewire, in fact don't like it but have some task to do, I was stuck in the problem, tried a lot of ways, then find your suggestion and it work thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
           @this.set('images','Hello');
           //console.log('Hello');
        });
</script>
```

Make a public property name 'images, initiate it in the mount. I hope it will solve your problem. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate the input field using inline scripts in livewire
like:

```js
document.addEventListener('livewire:load',function ()
        {
            @this.images = "Hello";
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="images" wire:model="images">
```

Comment: where should I add this event listener?

Comment: In your livewire blade file ... for reference: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts

Comment: is there a way to make the change without triggering a livewire update?

Answer (score 1):

Add **wire:ignore** on parent element of the input field

Like

```html
<div wire:ignore>

   <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="images" wire:model="images">

</div>
```